# Why is the challenge scalar multiplied with the private key scalar In the Schnorr identification protocol?

Tags: cryptography, schnorr-signatures, authentication

If Alice wants to prove to Bob she is the holder of private key `x`, without exposing `x`, they can use the Schnorr identification protocol which has the public function `sG = kG + exG` and the private scalar function `s = k +ex`. In these functions, `G` is the static generator point, `k` is a hidden nonce chosen by Alice to protect `x` from being revealed to Bob, and `e` is a nonce chose by Bob so that he can trust `kG` (can't be calculated by someone pretending to hold `x`).

This all makes sense to me, but I am curious if there is a reason that `e` is multiplied with `x` instead of just following the same addition operator as `k`. So the equations would become `sG = kG + eG + xG` and `s = k + e + x`. `k` has a very valid reason to use addition, that is how `x` remains hidden. I can't think of a meaningful difference for the goal of the protocol if `e` is multiplied or added, maybe I missing a core concept?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to Bitcoin. Perhaps this question would be more suitable for [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) (they even have a tag named [schnorr-identification](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/tags/schnorr-identification)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is trivial to forge.

Just to make sure we're on the same page, this is your protocol:

Alice has private key `x`, Bob has public key `Q`:

- Alice generates `k`, computes `R = kG`, and sends `R` to Bob.
- Bob generates `e`, and sends it to Alice.
- Alice computes `s = k + e + x`, and sends it to Bob.
- Bob verifies that `sG = R + eG + Q`.

---

Mallory is running your modified protocol with Bob, trying to pretend to be Alice.

- Mallory generates a random `k` and sends `R = kG - Q` to Bob.
- Bob generates `e` and sends it to Mallory.
- Mallory computes `s = k + e` and sends it to Bob.
- Bob verifies that `sG = R + eG + Q`. This will always hold.

Thus, Mallory successfully impersonated Alice, without having access to `x`.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!